# Java - executing command in UNIX environment

Tags: java, unix, process, runtime, exec

When I am trying to run a command in UNIX environment using

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("/bin/ksh -c \"ls -al\"")
```

That works as if the flags were discarded i.e. as if the command line interpreted this as "the first string until space counts". However, running this

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"/bin/ksh", "-c",  "ls -al"});
```

works as expected... Why??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Double quoted strings are a shell feature and `Runtime.exec()` does not invoke a shell to parse the command.

Comment: Ah.. if I run this command manually from shell, it works fine, but because Runtime is not a shell it does not parse the command the same way?

Comment: exactly, it doesn't deal with the double quoted strings, that's the point of the array argument.